# Explaining functions of Vigenère cipher

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, vigenere

i found the following code at http://rosettacode.org for the Vigenère cipher and i would like to undestand it better.

Could someone explain me what the single lines of code in `function ordA(a)` and in `function(a)` do?

```
function ordA(a) {
  return a.charCodeAt(0) - 65;
}

// vigenere
function vigenere2(text, key, decode) {
  var i = 0, b;
  key = key.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '');
  return text.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '').replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(a) {
    b = key[i++ % key.length];
    return String.fromCharCode(((ordA(a) + (decode ? 26 - ordA(b) : ordA(b))) % 26 + 65));
  });
}
```

Comment: 65 is the letter A

Comment: `ordA` takes an uppercase character and returns is offset from 'A'. for 'A' it's 0, for 'B' it's 1, ..., for 'Z' it's 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is supposed to be example code, but it mainly shows how not to program. Smart decisions *are* being made, but obviously the problem decomposition, variable naming and documentation leave a lot to be desired. Repeated code, convoluted lines, unexplained code fragments, the list goes on. Decode is a boolean, but the opposite of encryption is *decryption* not decoding. This code was made to *not* understand what is going on; what it does on the Rosetta site is mind-boggling in that respect.

---

returns an index in the English alphabet or ABC, assuming uppercase characters, 0 to 25 instead of 1 to 26 (because you can do modular calculations with zero indexing, not with one based indexing)

```
return a.charCodeAt(0) - 65;
```

---

function definition that takes a plaintext or ciphertext, a key which may be smaller than the plaintext and a Boolean to indicate if we're encoding or decoding

```
function vigenere2(text, key, decode)
```

---

index in plaintext and variable b, which will hold a character of the key for the index

```
var i = 0, b;
```

---

converts the key to uppercase and removed all characters not in the uppercase alphabet as well

```
key = key.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '');
```

---

this line is too long obviously; it converts the text to uppercase and removes the non-alphabet characters again

then it replaces the characters in the string using the function defined in the second argument of `replace`

```
return text.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '').replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(a) {
```

---

take the next character of the key in round robin fashion, using the modulus operator, update the index afterwards

```
b = key[i++ % key.length];
```

---

too much going on here, very bad program decomposition; in order of execution:

- `(decode ? 26 - ordA(b) : ordA(b))`: calculate a number in the range to update the index of the plaintext character; use the opposite value for decryption (wrongly called "decoding" here)
- `(ordA(a) + (decode ? 26 - ordA(b) : ordA(b))) % 26` perform the addition with the calculated number, reduce to 0 to 25 (i.e. when reaching Z continue with A and vice versa)
- `((ordA(a) + (decode ? 26 - ordA(b) : ordA(b))) % 26 + 65)` add 65 so the index is converted back into the ASCII index of uppercase characters, using two completely spurious parentheses
- finally, returns a string from one character code result, otherwise + will be addition instead of concatenation

```
return String.fromCharCode(((ordA(a) + (decode ? 26 - ordA(b) : ordA(b))) % 26 + 65));
```

---

well, it needed to end

```
  });
}
```

---

Let's show another way of programming this, using well named variables, functions for reused code and regular expressions that badly need a name to explain what they do.

```js
var ALPHABET_SIZE = 'Z'.charCodeAt(0) - 'A'.charCodeAt(0) + 1;

var encrypted = vigenere(false, "B", "Zaphod Breeblebox");
document.body.append('<div>' + encrypted + '</div>');
var decrypted = vigenere(true, "B", encrypted);
document.body.append('<div>' + decrypted + '</div>');

function vigenere(decrypt, key, text) {
    key = toJustUppercase(key);
    text = toJustUppercase(text);
  
    var textOffset = 0;
    // iterate over all characters, performing the function on each of them
    return text.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(textChar) {
        var keyChar = key[textOffset++ % key.length];
        var cryptedChar = substituteCharacter(decrypt, keyChar, textChar);
        return cryptedChar;
    });
}

function substituteCharacter(decrypt, keyChar, textChar) {
    var keyIndex = charToABCIndex(keyChar);
    if (decrypt) {
        // create the opposite of the encryption key index
        keyIndex = ALPHABET_SIZE - keyIndex;
    }
    
    var textIndex = charToABCIndex(textChar);

    // the actual Vigenere substitution, the rest is just indexing and conversion
    var substitutedIndex = (textIndex + keyIndex) % ALPHABET_SIZE;
      
    var substitutedChar = abcIndexToChar(substitutedIndex);
    return substitutedChar;
}

function toJustUppercase(text) {
    return text.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '')
}

function charToABCIndex(charValue) {
    return charValue.charCodeAt(0) - 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
}

function abcIndexToChar(index) {
    return String.fromCharCode(index + 'A'.charCodeAt(0));
}
```

Too many functions you say? Not really, I've not implemented `ord` and `chr`, or `vigenereEncrypt` and `viginereDecrypt` to make it even easier to read.

Comment: I would be very happy if somebody could explain to me why my constant definition cannot be moved down below.

Comment: I mainly programmed the snippet above to learn about the snippet toolbox thingy, but I don't think I got it completely right. Edits are very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your explanations and written code are going to help me alot.

Comment: No problem, glad this helped you out. One final note: obviously first converting to all uppercase and then only converting all uppercase is a bit, well, spurious as well.