# what type should i use instead of int or str?

Tags: python, encryption

At the first let me explain the code: my code is an encrypting code. at the first it gives two numbers then it have two encryption stages.
First stage, will reverse the text till the char that its index is equel with first number.
Second stage, will shift the chars of previous stage output in amount of their new location multiple by second number. and finally print what is encrypted. 
in this code i have problem with the 7th line of code.
don't know what type should i use for variables that are in 7th line. i receive error whether i use str or int.

```
first_num=int(input("Fnum: "))
second_num=input("Snum: ")
encrypt_stage1="".join(name[first_num-1::-1])+"".join(name[first_num::])

for place,char in enumerate(encrypt_stage1):
    ascii_code=ord(char)
    encryption_stage2=""
    encryption_stage2 += chr(str(int(ascii_code)+place*second_num))

print(encryption_stage2)
>>>TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'


----------
example of input: name=vahid, first_num=1, second_num=3
output will be: ygqus
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving

Comment: Also please give explicitly what you use for `first_num` and `second_num` so we can reproduce the error. I note you don't convert `second_num` to an `int` like you do for `first_num`. This may be part of the problem.

Comment: You should do encryption of _bytes_, not _strings_ or _integers_. Which Python version are you using? Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: converting second num to int wont cause an error?

Comment: Also, what is `name`? Please make sure you can exactly run the given example, with no other code.

Comment: name is what you wanna encrypt

Comment: I think you could learn a lot of my refactor of a code sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54867284/589259). You're trying too much on one line, use well named, short methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three problems:

- you forget to convert `second_num` to `int`
- you can't apply `chr()` to `str()`, I removed `chr()` call
- I have to move `encryption_stage2=""` outside the loop to not reassign it on every iteration

After dealing with these problems, the code looks like:

```
name = 'name'
first_num=int(input("Fnum: "))
second_num=int(input("Snum: "))
encrypt_stage1="".join(name[first_num-1::-1])+"".join(name[first_num::])

encryption_stage2=""
for place,char in enumerate(encrypt_stage1):
    ascii_code=ord(char)
    encryption_stage2 += str(int(ascii_code)+place*second_num)

print(encryption_stage2)
```

Comment: thanks for helping me. I'm beginner in python. but i doesn't give the out put that i want

Comment: You can provide the input `name`, `first_num`, `second_num` and expected output, after that somebody will be able to help you.